# how to move player smoothly between positions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public float movespeed = 0.0f;

private float x;
private float y;    
private float z;
private CharacterController controller;
private Vector3 moveDirection;

    void Update () {

            Vector3 pos = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform.position;

            x = pos.x;
            y = pos.y;
            z = pos.z;

            moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
                transform.position = new Vector3(-1.3f, y, z);
            else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
                transform.position = new Vector3(1.3f, y, z);

            //moveDirection.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movespeed;
            moveDirection.z = movespeed;    
            controller.Move (moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
        }
```

i want to make my player move between two points of x axis which are -1.3 and 1.3 and with this code above i am able to achieve that BUT it just teleports(i know thats how the code is made). i want the transition to be smooth. any ideas how can i achieve that?

Comment: you need to use LERP or SLERP over time

Comment: You can try `Vector3.MoveTowards()` or e.g `Vector3.Lerp().

Comment: The term for this is Tweening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to the above comments i was able to get it to work :)
the right thing to do here is to use SLerp. i used it like this:-

```
transform.position = Vector3.Slerp (pos, newPos, movespeed);
```

first i duplicated newPos with the values of pos and then changed only the x axis value(to get the desired result in my case) in newPos.